# Disable revisions for a specific post type only?

Tags: custom-post-types, revisions

Any way to disable post revision on specific post types only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `revisions` property inside the `supports` parameter of `register_post_type()`.

**Example**

```
$args = array(
    // ...
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','comments','revisions')
); 
register_post_type('book',$args);
```

Change to:

```
$args = array(
    // ...
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','comments')
); 
register_post_type('book',$args);
```

Comment: Actually it turned out that it is disabled by default... so.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't have control over the post type registration, you an use the remove_post_type_support() function:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'disablew_revisions');
function disable_revisions(){
    remove_post_type_support('post', 'revisions');
}
```

If you also wish to disable autosave for specific post types, you can do this:

```
add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'disable_autosave');
function disable_autosave(){
    global $post;
    if(get_post_type($post->ID) === 'post'){
        wp_deregister_script('autosave');
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. I'm thinking it might be a touch better to use `wp_dequeue_script` instead of `wp_deregister_script` for WP v 3.1+.